# Mysterious Ubuntu restart (with logs)

Tags: cron, reboot

My Ubuntu 13.10 was running a simulation that should last for days, but it for some reason rebooted automatically. The log said:

```
Dec 17 10:24:26 phz225 cron[1078]: (CRON) INFO (Running @reboot jobs)
```

So, it should have nothing to do with the hardware.

My question is: How to turn off this automatic rebooting? I routinely submit jobs that can last for days or weeks and I don't want to lose the results.

For you information, this is the [complete syslog.1](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7383429/syslog.1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line about @reboot jobs is printed *after* the system boots. A @reboot job is one that is set to automatically run on every boot. It is not a job that automatically reboots the system.

It looks like the last line that was logged before the system actually rebooted was this one:

```
Dec 17 09:46:02 phz225 whoopsie[1093]: online
```

It wasn't until several minutes later that rsyslogd logged the contents of the kernel ring buffer with the information logged during the boot process:

```
Dec 17 10:24:19 phz225 kernel: imklog 5.8.11, log source = /proc/kmsg started.
```

It's not obvious to me from the previous lines what may be going wrong with your system, but you should look at other possibilities than an automated reboot. I see no evidence of that.